# Using Message Selector on MQMD property

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to apply a Message Selector on an MQMD property `ApplIdentityData`

I can see this property is set on the message:

```
JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData=some_value
```

I have tried:

```
dest.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
dest.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT, 
                WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT);
/*1*/qsess.createReceiver(dest, "ApplIdentityData='some_value'");
/*2*/qsess.createReceiver(dest, "Root.MQMD.ApplIdentityData='some_value'");
```

They are not pulling in the message.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the fully qualified message header key in the selector. You may want to try this instead.

```
qsess.createReceiver(dest, "JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData='some_value'");
```

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm

Comment: The fully qualified header name is not accepted. Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with com
pcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2459' ('MQRC_SELECTOR_SYNTAX_ERROR').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.
java:203)

Comment: The documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm indicates only JMSDeliveryMode, JMSPriority, JMSMessageID, JMSTimestamp, JMSCorrelationID and JMSType properties having an equivalent mapping in MQMD can be used as message selectors. Other names like JMS_IBM_MQMD* are not allowed.